# LazyVGrid crashes

Tags: swiftui

I have a problem in an app on App Store that crashes and I cannot find the reason. I reduced the problem in a sample project and can repeat the crash with the following code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var items: [Int] = Array(0...40)
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 16) {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .frame(height: 135)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var columns: [GridItem] {
        [GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 16), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 16)]
    }
}
```

When I run it on my device, I get a crash after doing the following:

- scroll to the bottom
- rotate the device
- scroll to the top

What is going on? Is there something that I have missed, or is this actually a bug in LazyVGrid? The steps to reproduce this seem so simple, that I have a hard time believing that it has been missed by Apple, hence the question here...

I tried this on 4 different devices (2 iPads, 2 iPhones) and an iPad simulator, all running iOS 17.1 or 17.1.1. It failed every time on one of the iPads and one of the iPhones (and not on simulator), so it is not necessarily repeatable for everybody.

The crashing line in the code is just the main app entry point, and the message is something like "EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000001a582e454", so nothing helpful there...

Answer (score 3):

Seems this is a long term issue, discussed in the developer forums:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/718741

I can reproduce this in Xcode Version 15.1 beta 3 (15C5059c) deployed to iPhone 14 Pro Running 17.1.1. I noticed it only happens after a rotation where animation looks glitchy with the rectangles overlapping one another. Launch in portrait, scroll down, rotate to landscape then back to portrait (overlapping animation occurs), scroll to top, crash.

It even happens with Apple's example code in the docs for [LazyVGrid](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvgrid).

I noticed it doesn't crash when there is only one column.

Unrelated but it's not a good idea to use `id: \.self` because `self` is not a valid `id` and it can crash in a similar way, it can be made safer like this:

```
private let items: [Int] = Array(0...40) // private prevents changes being possible
```

or even better:

```
ForEach(0..<41) { item in // static range is now impossible to change
```

Comment: No, that was not the reason. It still crashes.
BTW: I believe that \.self is allowed - it refers to the Int in the array. Paul Hudson has explained it here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/why-does-self-work-for-foreach

Comment: Agreed. Although self is often misused in situations where it isn’t unique, it should work here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this. Cannot believe that Apple has not fixed this yet when it's such an old issue. As one of the comments in the developer forum writes: "Please care more about SwiftUI" . It looks like I have to create a SwiftUI wrapper around UICollectionView instead then 

Answer (score 1):

In my case at least, disabling the animation of the LazyVGrid works. This has only been confirmed in the simulator so far but it consistently crashes in the simulator without this.

```
LazyVGrid {
// Insert code...
}
.transaction { transaction in
    transaction.animation = nil
}
```

I got the suggestion from here: https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/disable-animations-transactions/ While it does not say it will fix the crash, I took a chance on it and it seems to work.

Comment: transaction - didn't help

Comment: for such uncorrected years! errors Apple must pay compensation for damages.
I can’t imagine Toyota releasing a car for which:
- go back
- rotated 90 degrees
- go forward
bam and the car fell apart